# How to include unmanaged reference in Windows Store App

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows Store Application.  I am trying to reference a library that has this dependency structure:

- unmanaged.dll
- managedWrapper.dll (depends on unmanaged.dll)

From my Windows Store App project, I can only reference the managed assembly managedWrapper.dll.  I get an error if I try to reference unmanaged.dll, something akin to "unable to add reference".

My project compiles fine, however at runtime I get a file not found exception because managedWrapper.dll cannot find unmanaged.dll.  I kind of expected this behavior but don't know how to fix it.  The problem is I am trying to debug my application, but I have no idea how Visual Studio 2012 deploys it.  I can only explicitly reference managedWrapper.dll in my project, so there is no way to tell Visual Studio that unmanaged.dll is also a dependency for my application.  Since I have no idea how Visual Studio deploys my Windows Store Application when debugging, I don't know where to manually copy unmanaged.dll to get around the problem.

Also there doesn't seem to be a way to get the actual working directory of my App while debugging, so again I don't know where to copy unmanaged.dll to so managedWrapper.dll won't fail at runtime.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add unmanaged.dll as a file to your Windows Store Application. Make sure you set the build properties for unmanaged.dll to Content, and set it to Copy to Output.

This should copy the dll to the output directory.

The above should work, but may not be ideal in the case where you have multiple projects that reference managed.dll. For example, if you also have a unit test project that references managed.dll, you will have to do the above and add unmanaged.dll to it as well.